# PHP5-fpm fails to start

Tags: debian, php5, php-fpm, dotdeb

When i start my debian box, php5-fpm says that it's failed to start. 
When i check the logs it says that port 900 is taken. But that couldn't be becouse there's nothing else runnong on port 9000. And the weirdest thing is that after it say's it has failed to start, php is running...

The package php5-fpm is from the dotdeb repo. 
Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
netstat -tunap | grep 9000
```

to find out what is running on this port

Comment: IT seems that only php5-fpm is running on that port!?